# Set default value input tag Django

Tags: python, django, input, django-views

IN HTML :
`<div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 1vh;"> <input name="gen_down" type="number" class="form-control"  /> <span class="input-group-text">%</span> </div>`

IN VIWES.py:
`gen_down = int(request.POST.get('gen_down', 0))`

Run in Terminal:
gen_down = int(request.POST.get('gen_down', 0))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 2):

Can be as simple as:

```py
gen_down = int(request.POST.get('gen_down') or 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, the error say that we cannot do int() to a int value which in our case is zero so the solution is to return zero but in string format.
Like this :

```
gen_down=int(request.POST.get('gen_down', "0")
```